# json.stringify is adding extra backslashes in res.send()

Tags: json, typescript, api, express, postman

My API needs to return the following data in it's response.

```
{ users: 'All users are as follows: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]'}
```

It should be a json object with one of the key values is a json array. However, the json array is turned into a string because it needs to be appended onto another string. My code is like this:

```
const array = [{id: 1}, {id:2}]
const string = 'All users are as follows: ' + JSON.stringify(array)
res.send({users: string})
```

I use Express for my API. When I check the response in postman it add many backslashed onto the string. However, when I do console.log({a: string}) locally, I don't see any of those slashes.
this is what I see:

```
{users: "[{\"id\":1}, {\"id\":2}]"}
```

Comment: Are you sure those extra backslashes are actually in the string and are not just in the representation of the string you're looking at?  For example, `console.log("\"".length)` produces `1`, because `"\""` is just the way you represent a string consisting of a quotation mark in JavaScript.  There is no backslash in the string itself.

Comment: that might be true actually. I see these \  in postman when I receive the response but when I do console.log() with exact same thing, I don't see those backslashes. but is there any way that I can get rid of them when I see the response in Postman

Comment: I don't know.. you might want to tag this question with "postman" and see if someone knows

Comment: okay thanks! I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   {users: "[{\"id\":1}, {\"id\":2}]"}
```

is the json representation of response , in json string is represented by enclosing it with double quotes (") and so if the string itself contains double quotes then it should be escaped.

```
     { "user": " "name" " } , is invalid  you should use { "user" : "\"name\""}
```

when you print it in console it prints only the escaped charater thats why you don't see " but ".

learn more about javascript grammer at :

https://www.crockford.com/mckeeman.html

when you use JSON.stringify() it converts it into valid JSON string , you cannot send it without it because it will send it as javascript object and not as valid json. using

res.send ({name:"test"}} will send response as [object][object]

**so the only way to get what you want is to send the response as text and not JSON:**

```
const array = [{id: 1}, {id:2}]
const string = 'All users are as follows: ' + JSON.stringify(array)
res.send(`{users: "${string}" }`)
```

here in res.send  isntead of {users:string} , we are using "users:string" .

NOTE: its not valid JSON

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: ahh man. I guess i'll have to keep the backslashes then. Thanks your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your code on returning your response.

Anyways, I do it this way.

```
let object = {name: "Juan Dela Cruz"}

res.send(object)
```

Comment: I did post my code. I do basically the same thing but the key value is string with a json array inside it. So, taking your code mine is like this:

Comment: let object = {name: "all names are" + JSON.stringify( [ {name: "name1"}, {name: "name2"} ] )" }

Comment: res.send(object)

Comment: In my code, I did the JSON.stringify part earlier and and saved it to a variable

Comment: I think that normal in JSON.stringify function denoting that you have string inside a string.

Comment: What you can do in order to transform your JSON string into JSON object you may use JSON.parse

Comment: How would I do that? because my JSON starts an object which I then change into a string. wouldn't json.parse take me backwards?